# Nighttime reentry of occupied spacecraft?

Tags: crewed-spaceflight, reentry

In looking at details of the tomorrow early morning (Sunday, May 2, 2021) reentry of the crewed SpaceX Dragon capsule, I see that it's reentry plan is for a nighttime splashdown in the Gulf of Mexico.  I know the Space Shuttle did some nighttime landings, but those were landing on runways, not in a huge body of water.

Having a nighttime landing into water seems much more inherently risky in regards to visibility of spotting the descending spacecraft, finding it in the water, and safely bringing it on board a recovery craft with so much less visibility compared to daytime.  So my question - have there been previous splashdowns of crewed spacecraft at nighttime?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, [Apollo 8 in 1968](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_8) reentered at night, splashing down a couple of hours before dawn. After splashdown, the crew were secure in the capsule, so [they simply waited for sunrise for the recovery operation to proceed.](https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/americanexperience/features/moon-apollo-8-insider-stories/)

Comment: why didn't they just transmit their GPS coordinates (humor)

Comment: @uhoh: It was too dark for them to see which buttons to press ;-)